# Mirror problems after building game in unity

Tags: unity, assets, build-process

Hi I am facing a weird problem in unity when I build a particular scene.

Here is the screenshot of how the mirror looks when I play the game from inside the unity editor:

[image: mirror view from inside unity editor]

And here is how it looks once I build this scene and then play it:

[image: mirror view inside a built game]

The quality settings at Edit->Project Settings->Quality are these:

[image]

And the player settings at File->Build Settings->Player Settings are these:

[image]

So how do I fix this? What do I need to change or is there any other entity?

Comment: Check your quality settings. `Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality`.  Your editor is likely running at a higher quality setting than the build.

Comment: Ok, so it wasn't quality settings.  I've got no other ideas. :\

Comment: Can you take the screenshots from the same angle, please?